# What does BE and BQ stand for (or mean) on a font name?

Tags: typography

I have noticed that some fonts have the letters BE or BQ appended to their name. What does this mean? Is this a standard code for some features of the font? Extra glyphs perhaps? Or is this just a naming convention of a specific foundry?

For example, what is the difference between these two fonts? I am trying to decide which one to buy. The price is exactly the same.

[Akzidenz Grotesk BE](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/berthold/akzidenz-grotesk-be/)

[Akzidenz Grotezk BQ](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/berthold/akzidenz-grotesk-bq/)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**What do they mean?**

The BQ and BE OpenType Basic versions correspond to the Berthold BQ and Adobe BE PostScript Type 1 Legacy versions.

**What is the difference**

The Berthold BQ and Adobe Berthold versions are derived from the same data    source and so the character outlines are almost identical. The metrics (spacing and kerning) will differ considerably as the Berthold BQ versions have extended kerning for European languages (German, French, Italian etc.). Other additional benefits of the Berthold BQ versions include:

- The Berthold BQ versions sometimes offer weights and versions not available in the Adobe Berthold versions (e.g. Imago, Bodoni Old Face
  Expert).
- Berthold BQ versions always offer full character sets whereas some of the Adobe Expert fonts have incomplete character sets.
- Some of the most popular Berthold BQ versions include the EURO symbol

Kudos for Illan and Glen for pointing me towards the right direction.

Comment: I think you should mark this as answered. Good question though!

Comment: Thanks! I can't mark it until 2 days because I answered myself.

Comment: It's absolutely not "bad taste" to answer your own question! [It's encouraged!](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: @cockypup 2nd link seems to be dead now, but thanks very much for the answer!  Seems like anyone would want the BQ version.

Comment: @MattMc: Thanks for noticing the broken link. I have removed both links just in case.

Answer (score 4):

It is probably short for "[Berthold Exklusivs](http://www.bertholdtypes.com/blog/2010-12-08/developing-the-berthold-exklusiv-collection/)" collection.

Comment: +1 Hmmm. Interesting. That would be BE. What about BQ?

Comment: @cockypup Quality (or the German word for that)

Comment: http://desktoppub.about.com/od/typefoundries/a/Type-Foundry-Abbreviations-In-Fonts.htm

Comment: @Glen The Udderboat: good find.

Comment: Short *for* is what we'd say in English.

Answer (score 1):

This will answer your questions. E is for exclusive and Q for Quality http://desktoppub.about.com/od/typefoundries/a/Type-Foundry-Abbreviations-In-Fonts.htm